# Error initializing classpath: Could not determine java version from '11.0.3'. Grails run-app

Tags: java, grails

While starting the app I am getting this error

```
F:\Projects\Java Projects\grailsAjax>grails run-app
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/C:/grails-3.3.10/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/jars/groovy-2.4.17.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
| Error Error initializing classpath: Could not determine java version from '11.0.3'. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Java Version

```
C:\>java -version
java version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Grails Version

```
C:\>grails -version
| Grails Version: 3.3.10
| JVM Version: 11.0.3
```

Comment: Grails 3 only supports jdk 7 and 8 - and while the docs are written as "at least" - 8 is the cap.  Grails 4 will most likely be fine with the newest JDKs.

Comment: Downgraded jdk to 8 and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grail 3.x supports jdk 7 and 8. I downgraded my jdk version to 8 and now the error is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Grails-3.3.x is supports JDK-7/8 only. From the Grails documentation Grails-4 is certified on jdk-11